# Intent not going to the correct activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a game as an app. I have one screen which is just three buttons, Edit, Play and Exit. When I click on the Edit button, it goes to PlayTheGame, and not to the correct activity (EditWords). The same thing happens when I click on the Exit button, and it goes to the PlayTheGame activity and not exiting the app.
What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix my code so that the buttons go to the correct activities?
Thank you in advance for any and all help you can provide me.

**Here is the code**

```
    l = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(theGame.this, EditWords.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });

    x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ptg);
    x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(theGame.this, PlayTheGame.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    });

    e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

**Corresponding xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/screen1"
tools:context="ariel.executioner.theGame"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Edit Words" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ptg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Play The Game" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="exit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add `finish();` when start the new activity.

Comment: are you sure the ID in your layouts are correctly set ? Moreover, don't use `System.exit(0)`, it's a bad practice

Comment: id's are correct

Comment: show your xml layout file

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: XMLfile has been posted

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall apk -> Clean the project -> try to build again.**
Also if you want to exit the entire app use, `finish()` and `finishAffinity()`

Comment: I would give this a try as well. Also invalidating the cache and restarting.

Comment: thank you that helped, and the exit button works now. although the two other buttons still go to the "play the game" file.

Comment: In EditWords class and PlayTheGame class ,check if you are having the same layout file by mistake, so it seems that it opens the same PlayTheGame class.

Comment: Uninstall apk -> Clean the project -> try to build again. -this didnt work either